# Meteor client side only publish subscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor has this live templating feature where when data changes it can update the HTML in the page automagically. How can I use this feature client side only? Using pseudo code the simplest example might be a clock. Effectively I want to do something like this

```
<template name="clock">
  <div>{{time}}</div>
</template>
```

Then completely on the client side I effectively want to be able to do something like this

```
function publishTheTime() {
   var timeStr = (new Date()).toString();
   Meteor.somePublishFunction({time: timeStr});
}
setTimeout(publishTheTime, 5000);
```

And have meteor update the time in the html.

Once I get that working I'd like to take it a step further. Imagine I have clocks by city. You can think of this as a database of `Cities` where the `_id` for each is the name of the city and the only other field is its `time`. Again 100% on the client side, I'd like to be able to show the times updated live for N countries. Something like

```
<template name="cities">
  <div class="cities">
    {{#each cities}}
      {{> city}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="city">
  <div class="city">
    <div>name: {{_id}}</div>
    <div>time: {{time}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Can I do this 100% on the client? There's no need for full database and nothing needs to be on the server but I still need to able to select cities as in

```
Cities.find({_id: {$in: ["Vancover", "New York City", "London"]}})
```

and all similar stuff.

Comment: There are several examples provided in the meteor repo.  One is a [client side reactive clock](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/examples/clock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an *unmanaged local collection*. It's a collection that you define on the client which is not synchronized with the server, but otherwise retains the same properties as a normal collection. For more details, have a close look at the [collections section](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection) of the docs.

You can do something like this:

```
Cities = new Meteor.Collection(null);
Cities.insert({_id: 'Seattle', time: new Date});
console.log(Cities.findOne());
```